# WordPress Custom rewrite does not work with seo url

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I try to generate 3 custom rewrite rule, it does not really work very well.

Here is my plugin class file.

```
<?php

class QuestionAndAnswers
{
    public $isUserLoggedIn; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isUserLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
         
        add_action( 'init', [$this, 'loginRegisterRewrites'], 10, 0 );
        add_filter( 'query_vars', [$this, 'loginRegisterQueryVars'] );
        add_action( 'parse_request', [$this, 'loginRegisterParseRequest'] ); 

    }

    public function loginRegisterRewrites()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule( '/uyelik/uye-girisi$', 'index.php?custom_param=login', 'top' );
        add_rewrite_rule( '/uyelik/yeni-uyelik$', 'index.php?custom_param=register', 'top' );
        add_rewrite_rule( '/uyelik/profilim$', 'index.php?custom_param=profile', 'top' );
    }

    public function loginRegisterQueryVars($queryVars)
    {
        $queryVars[] = 'custom_param';
        return $queryVars;
    }

    public function loginRegisterParseRequest( &$wp )
    {
        if ( array_key_exists( 'custom_param', $wp->query_vars ) )
        {
            $templateFile = $wp->query_vars['custom_param'];
            if(strlen($templateFile) > 0)
            {
                if($templateFile=='profile')
                {
                    get_template_part( 'core/templates/modules/' . $templateFile);
                    exit;
                }
                if(!$this->isUserLoggedIn) {
                    get_template_part( 'core/templates/modules/' . $templateFile);
                } else {
                    wp_redirect( home_url().'/home' );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
}

new QuestionAndAnswers();
```

When i try with domain.tld/index.php?custom_param=login it works well, but domain.tld//uyelik/uye-girisi not work.

PS : I flushed rewrite rules on admin panel also.